# Master Slave Error user specified as a definer ('dbadmin'@'%') does not exist

Tags: mysql, replication

I setup mysql (version 5.5) master slave replication and when test it with root user from phpmyadmin data succesfully transferd. When start application slave have an error:

```
mysql> show slave status\G
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: 
                  Master_Host: 10.1.1.31
                  Master_User: slave_user
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 6963420
               Relay_Log_File: mysql-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 529310
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: No
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB: 
          Replicate_Ignore_DB: 
           Replicate_Do_Table: 
       Replicate_Ignore_Table: 
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table: 
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table: 
                   Last_Errno: 1449
                   Last_Error: Error 'The user specified as a definer ('dbadmin'@'%') does not exist' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'update mytbl 
                                        set ....limit 1'
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 6300951
              Relay_Log_Space: 1191935
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File: 
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File: 
           Master_SSL_CA_Path: 
              Master_SSL_Cert: 
            Master_SSL_Cipher: 
               Master_SSL_Key: 
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error: 
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1449
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'The user specified as a definer ('dbadmin'@'%') does not exist' on query. Default database: 'mydb'. Query: 'update mytbl 
                                        set ....limit 1'
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids: 
             Master_Server_Id: 1
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

How to solve it ? maybe just add user 'dbadmin'@'%'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same issue and fixed it.
Just create user 'dbadmin'@'%' - try it!